# Python: Adding list to array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am trying to learn how arrays work and I have a problem. I want to add list to array and I am unable to do so.
Example:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
array = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6])
print(array)
```

And I want the output to be:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
[3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

I also want to add new list every iteration.
Thx for answers!

Comment: How would you expect `list` to be in ? You don't use it. Why use a numpy array ?

Comment: This is not the way to learn how arrays work.  That desired output is a nested list, not an array.  Stick with list methods for this kind of work.

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between Python `list` and `array`?

Answer (score 0):

I you want your `list` to be included, use it in the array construction. Not that if the sublist length doesn't match, they keep being python `list`, if they are same list, it becomes a 2d numpy array

```
import numpy as np

values = [1, 2, 3]
array = np.array([values, [3, 4, 5, 6]])
print(array)  # [list([1, 2, 3]) list([3, 4, 5, 6])]

values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array = np.array([values, [3, 4, 5, 6]])
print(array)
# [[1 2 3 4]
#  [3 4 5 6]]
```

---

But if you don't need numpy operation, you should stick to python `list`

```
values = [1, 2, 3]
array = [values, [3, 4, 5, 6]]
print(array)  # [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: In a new enough numpy version that first `np.array` will issue a long warning about making a ragged array.  That should be a clue that it is not a desirable action.